# How do a IN Query with parameter in mongo template

Tags: spring, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

I'm new in spring I would traduce This query  in a mongo template Query.
Can someone help me?

```
public List<Prodotto>selectedList(List<Integer>categories){
        
                TypedQuery<Product> findSelectedQuery1 = em
                        .createQuery( "SELECT DISTINCT p FROM Product p WHERE p.category.idCategory IN :categories ",
                                Product.class);
                findSelectedQuery1.setParameter("categories", categories);
                
                return findSelectedQuery1.getResultList();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your "category" is an object

```
db.Product.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "category.idCategory": {
        $in: categories
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iKLKus1ksjR)

Spring-Data:

```
@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

...

List<AggregationOperation> pipeline = new ArrayList<>();

//$match
pipeline.add(Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("category.idCategory").in(categories)));

Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(pipeline);
return mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, Product.class, Product.class).getMappedResults();
```